# Show that any compact set in $\mathbb{C}$ is the spectrum of an operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have been looking around for an example of a general continuous (bounded) linear operator, who's spectrum is any compact set $K\subset\mathbb{C}$.

I have seen an example, where we take the set $\{\alpha_n\}$ to be a countable dense subset of $K$. Let $H$ be a hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, define the operator $T:H\to H$ such that:

$T(u)=\sum_n\alpha_n\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n.$ I can see that any eigenvalue of $T$ is some $\alpha_j\in\{\alpha_n\}$ since:

$Tu-\lambda u=0\Rightarrow \sum_n\alpha_n\langle u ,e_n \rangle e_n-\sum_n\lambda\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n=0$ Now each $i$-th term gives us:

$\alpha_iu_i-\lambda u_i=0\Rightarrow \lambda = \alpha_i$ so we know that every value in $\{\alpha_n\}$ is in the spectrum of $T$ so we see that the spectrum is at least a dense subset of $K$.

But this is where I am stuck and would appreciate help/ explaining what comes next.
Thanks!

Comment: The spectrum is always closed, so $\sigma(T) \supset \overline{\{\alpha_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}} = K$. On the other hand, it is not hard to see that if $\lambda\notin K$ then $\lambda I - T$ is invertible.

Comment: Yes, but how do we go the other way i.e. $\sigma(T)\subset\overline{\{\alpha_n:n\in\mathbb{N}}\}$

Comment: As we then need to show that the resolvent exists, is bounded and is densely defined in $H$. I see existence and boundedness, but not necessarily densely defined?

Comment: That's what the second sentence is about. If $\lambda \notin K$, then $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$.

Comment: Could you show me why? that is the bit I'm stuck on, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By construction, every $\alpha_k$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, hence we have

$$K = \overline{\{\alpha_k : k\in\mathbb{N}\}} \subset \sigma(T).$$

On the other hand, if $\lambda\notin K$, then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert\lambda - \alpha_k\rvert > \delta$ for all $k$, and then we find the inverse of $\lambda I - T$ explicitly:

$$\begin{align}
(\lambda I - T)\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} y_n\cdot e_n\right) &= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n e_n\\
\iff \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (\lambda - \alpha_n)y_n e_n &= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n e_n\\
\iff \bigl(\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\bigr)\bigl( (\lambda-\alpha_n)y_n &= x_n\bigr)\\
\iff \bigl(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\bigr)\biggl(y_n &= \frac{1}{\lambda-\alpha_n}x_n\biggr),
\end{align}$$

so

$$(\lambda I - T)^{-1}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n e_n\right) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{x_n}{\lambda-\alpha_n}e_n.$$

Since $\lvert\lambda - \alpha_n\rvert > \delta$ for all $n$, we have $\left\lvert\frac{1}{\lambda-\alpha_n}\right\rvert < \frac{1}{\delta}$, and so $(\lambda I - T)^{-1}$ is a globally defined continuous operator, hence $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$, which yields the other inclusion $\sigma(T) \subset K$, altogether $\sigma(T) = K$.

Comment: One thing, the sums and sets should all be over $\mathbb{Q}$, since $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\{\alpha_n\}$ is dense subset of $K$ i.e. all values in $K$ with rational coeffiencents. Anyway, would the last series converge $\forall x\in H$?

Comment: I assumed the $\alpha_n$ were $\mathbb{N}$-indexed. The bound $\left\lvert \frac{1}{\lambda-\alpha_n}\right\rvert < \frac{1}{\delta}$ ensures the convergence, since $$\sum \left\lvert \frac{x_n}{\lambda-\alpha_n}\right\rvert^2 \leqslant \sum \delta^{-2}\lvert x_n\rvert^2 < \infty$$ follows from $\sum \lvert x_n\rvert^2 < \infty$.

Comment: So should I choose $H $ to     be $l^2(\mathbb {Q})$?

Comment: Careful. $K$ need not contain any point with rational coefficients, so taking $\{\alpha_n\}$ to be the points in $K$ with rational coefficients doesn't work then. What one does is take any countable dense subset of $K$, and countable means we can index by $\mathbb{N}$. We could also index by other sets, and we can even take a nonseparable Hilbert space, e.g. $\ell^2(K)$ (if $K$ is countable, that is separable), with all $\alpha\in K$ as eigenvalues.

Comment: But often taking a countable set indexable by $\mathbb { N } $ may not be dense in $K $. Without specifying $H $, how did you justify the convergence of that last series?

Comment: Every subset of $\mathbb{C}$ has a countable (finite or countably infinite) dense subset, since the topology of $\mathbb{C}$ is second countable. We don't need to know what $H$ is, since the $e_n$ were chosen to be an orthonormal basis (aka Hilbert basis), so $\sum\lvert\langle u,e_n\rangle\rvert^2<\infty$ for all $u\in H$, and if $\sum\lvert x_n\rvert^2<\infty$, there is an $u\in H$ with $x_n=\langle u,e_n\rangle$ for all $n$, regardless of what the index set is. In $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$, every coefficient is multiplied with a complex number, bounded independently of $n$, so the multiplied

Comment: series converges when the original series converges.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to put: $\sum|\frac{\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n}{\lambda-\alpha_n}|\leq \frac{1}{\delta}\|x\|?$

Comment: We need the squares, in general $\sum \lvert \langle x,e_n\rangle\rvert = +\infty$.

Comment: I thought the sum was equivalent to the norm?

Comment: No, we have $$\lVert x\rVert^2 = \sum \lvert \langle x,e_n\rangle\rvert^2$$ with the squares. Think of the $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ spaces. The Hilbert space $\ell^2$ is different from the space $\ell^1$. The unsquared sum corresponds to $\ell^1$.

Comment: Sorry, so what assumptions are you placing upon $H$ to make sure $\sum |x_n|^2\lt\infty$

Comment: What you wrote in the question, that it is a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$.

Comment: I see! is this Bessel's inequality?

Comment: More Parseval's identity, the case where Bessel's inequality becomes an equality.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for helping!

Comment: I Am very confused, I submitted this for my homework and my lecturer said it was wrong, but I'm so sure this is right, is it me or him?

Comment: The result is right, the argument we have here too. It is of course possible that you made a mistake writing it up, things got a bit scattered here. Without seeing what you submitted, I cannot tell. Can you show me what you submitted?

Comment: They are the same, my lecturers argument was that my operator was not compact since thé sequence of $\alpha_n$ does not go to zero, but I fail to see how this is relevant?

Comment: Wait. That's the first time it is mentioned that the operator should be compact. The question said "continuous (bounded)". If it shall be the spectrum of a _compact_ operator, that is different. Not every compact set in $\mathbb{C}$ is the spectrum of a compact operator. The spectrum of a compact operator contains only countably many points, and no point except $0$ can be an accumulation point of the spectrum.

Comment: I'm well aware, it's not part of the question thats why I'm confused that it's relevant!

Comment: Well, scrutinise the assignment once more, carefully, to see whether that says the operator should be compact. If it doesn't, go to your lecturer and tell him that compactness of the operator wasn't asked for. If it does say that, go to your lecturer and tell him that you overlooked that part.

Comment: I've just rechecked the sheet, and this is the question word for word:

Let $K$ be an arbitrary compact set in $\mathbb{C}$. Give an example of a continuous linear operator $T$ such that the spectrum of $~T$ equals $K$, in symbols, $\sigma(T)=K$

Comment: Okay, then it's a mistake of your lecturer (or grader, whatever). It is not required that $T$ be compact, and for an arbitrary compact $K$, that is also not possible. So when marking the exercises (s)he thought the operator should have been compact, but it wasn't so. Go (calmly and politely) and make him/her aware of the mistake. That ought to rectify it.

Comment: Okay thank you! this is just so frustrating, because I'm seeing alot of mistakes he's making, such as proofs in the notes, bu my exam is in less than a month, and I don't know if I should write the wrong things just to get the marks!

Comment: Ouch! That's bad. Don't take my word for it, but I think it would be better to write the right things, and if the need arises, appeal to a higher authority.

Comment: in general I would (I refuse to write things that don't make sense), but I would never get to see my exam paper so I'd never know :(

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that a non-empty set $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is given and choose a dense sequence $(\lambda_n)$ in $K$. If $T$ is the corresponding diagonal operator, $T(e_n)=\lambda_n e_n$, then 
${\rm sp}(T)=\overline{\{\lambda_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}}=K$.
 Thus, the spectrum is an arbitrary non-empty compact set in general.