# compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is spectrum. (Banach space / hilbert space)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I'm studying that what set can be the spectrum of operator.

> If $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite dimension Hilbert space and $K$ is a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, show that there is an $A$ in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ such that $\sigma(A) = K$ .

[Show that any compact set in $\mathbb{C}$ is the spectrum of an operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740904/show-that-any-compact-set-in-mathbbc-is-the-spectrum-of-an-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1)
This is related question about this question. But it gave an answer when $\mathcal{H}$ is separable, not the infinite dimension case. But I believe that my question can be reduced to link. How to do that.

In addition, what about this question?

> If $K$ is a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, does there exist an operator $A$ in $\mathcal{B}(C[0,1])$ such that $\sigma(A) = K$ .

I saw the result that in Banach space, this property does not hold in general, but I think in this case, we can find this one, but I cannot find this example with above example. can you help me?

Comment: Try to do the same thing as in the link : take a Hilbert basis $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ and do as in the link for a dense subset $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a countable subfamily $(e_{i_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$; define the operator on the $e_i$, $i \in I \setminus \{ i_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ by mapping $e_i$ to $\lambda e_i$ for a fixed $\lambda \in K$. I think this should work

Comment: @AlexL Thanks. I think this work too! Do you have any idea of second one?

Comment: If I remember $C([0,1])$ is separable and a Hilbert basis is $t \mapsto e^{2ni\pi t}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @AlexL Thank you! I think you are right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexL: I'm not sure I understand your proposed argument for the second question. You can write down an operator as in the first construction but with no guarantee that it's an operator on $C([0, 1])$.

Comment: I refer to the link in the question. $C([0,1])$ is separable so one can do as in the link

Comment: @AlexL I think Qiaochu is right because this treat about $B(C[0,1])$.

Comment: Is $\ {\cal B}(C[0,1])\ $ the set of *bounded* linear operators on $\ C[0,1]\ $?  If so, with respect to which norm? Under the uniform norm, $\ C[0,1]\ $ is a Banach space, but not a Hilbert space. And the Hilbert space spanned by the functions $\ \{e^{2n\pi it}\}_{n=0}^\infty\ $ (under the $ {\mathscr L}^2\ $ norm) is a strict superset of $\ C[0,1]\ $, in which it is dense, but since it isn't complete under that norm it isn't a Hilbert space under it.

Comment: @Ionza leggiera Yes. Under uniform norm is right. I misunderstood too. Not complete under the norm.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood the second question. Deeply sorry

Comment: So you look at $C([0,1])$ as a Banach space for the uniform norm. What if you build an operator $T$ as in the link for $L^2([0,1])$ with respect to the imaginary exponential maps. Then you can restrict $T$ to $C([0,1])$, with is continuous wrt the $L^2$ norm. But for continuous functions, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2} \leqslant \Vert \cdots \Vert_\infty$, so $T$ is in $B(C([0,1])$ for the uniform norm. Then you need to check that the spectrum of $T$ is $K$ as in the link

Comment: This is a general idea, I don't know if it actually works as expected

Comment: Thanks, i will try with this scheme.

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, the spectrum of the multiplication operator $g\mapsto fg$ on $C[0,1]$ coincides with the range of $f$, so this gives lots of examples (think of space filling curves) but unfortunately only path connected sets :-(

Comment: @AlexL, I am afraid your idea might not work because the range of the restricted operator might not be in $C[0,1]$.